# ROS velodyne VLP-32c play pcap file ghost effect

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Environment: Ubuntu 18.04
ROS DISTRO: melodic
LiDAR: VLP-32C

I am trying to convert .pcap obtained from VLP-32c to .pcd file. But I found that there is a ghost effect for each moving vehicle (but not for all). I also tried to visualize the .pcap file using rviz. But the ghost effect still exists.
Here are some examples:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14SN-BM3HQesi2S4tH7vHYY-aUwK97DeG

The method that I used to read point cloud from VLP-32c was:
roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP-32C_points.launch pcap:="path/to/pcap"
The method used to convert pcap to pcd was:
rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/velodyne_points _prefix:=/path/to/pcd

I am wondering how to fix this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402670/ros-velodyne-vlp-32c-play-pcap-file-ghost-effect/) by [Skywalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/108773/skywalker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think what you are seeing is multiple device 360-degree scans being put into the same pointcloud. Maybe you have not set some parameter the `velodyne driver` needs (e.g. to tell the driver the correct model, or to tell it the hardware's RPM value), or it is a bug in the `velodyne_driver` code related to reading from a file (instead of a network socket.)

http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_driver

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Skywalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/108773/skywalker/) on 2022-06-23**:
Thank you for the answers. Yes, I figured that I didn't config the "cut_angle" to 3.14 since I was using 0-180 degrees of view.
I found the answer here:
https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/248
Hope this can help others with the same issue.